# Parse file and interpret php code in it without php tags

Tags: php, file

I have a text file with the follow content:

```
This is a static content

{{ echo "Hello World" }}
```

The file is named `test.txt`

What I want is to parse this file using PHP and create a new file with the following content:

```
This is a static content

Hello World
```

As you can see the code inside the curly braces: {{}} needs to be executed before save to the target file. I don't know where to start to achieve my goal.

Comment: use a template engine which accepts plugins as well, i think this is what is needed in your qustion, instead of developing a template engine all over (except if you want to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/', function($match) {
    ob_start();
    eval($match[1] . ';');
    $out = ob_get_clean();

    return $out;
}, $string);
```

should do the job.

Demo: http://3v4l.org/nYT31

Comment: your solution is working perfectly, but do you know any other approach without eval (some hosting provider don't allow eval).

Comment: Not if you want to execute php code, sorry. Maybe you want build a template parser like Smarty o Twig